# How to allow squid user to use only certain ports that are bound to ip

Tags: linux, proxy, ip, port, squid

In my squid configuration, I map each ip to a specific port.

```
acl port_3000_acl myport 3000
acl port_3001_acl myport 3001

http_port 3000
http_port 3001

tcp_outgoing_address 185.166.196.238 port_3000_acl
tcp_outgoing_address 218.151.231.148 port_3001_acl
```

The problem is that each user can use any port. I considered the solution to run a separate instance of squid for each user, but it seemed to me that this was a very non-scalable solution.
How can I allow the user to use only specific ports? Thanks